# CSS/Javascript picture transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small picture, which is in a gallery. If you click on it, it should appear underneath in big.

```
<a class="lilPic1Link" >
    <img src="resources/littleFlyingDoggScreen1.png" alt="Willkommen-Screen" width="52" height="93" id="lilPic1" onClick="makePicBig('resources/flyingDoggScreen1.PNG')">
</a>
```

Following: The bigPic:

```
<img id="bigPic" alt="game-picture" width="1" height="1" >
```

The Javascript function for that one:

```
function onLoadFunction() {
    document.getElementById("bigPic").style.visibility = "hidden";                
}

function makePicBig(sourceString) {
    document.getElementById("bigPic").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("bigPic").src = sourceString;
}
```

The first function makes the pic invisible at the start and the second sets the source of the bigPic to the sourche, which is wanted.

Now i don´t want the pic to just come up, but want it to smooth in from like 1px * 1px to 320px * 586px.
In CSS I would just make a transition like :

```
#bigPic{
    transition: width 3s, height 3s;
}
#bigPic:hover{
    width: 320px;
    height: 586px;
}
```

But I don´t want to hover over the picture again. If you click the little one, the bigPic should smooth in like I said. Is there any way to do that?
The three pics are the small ones. The bigPic should appear underneath them.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQUERY

```
function makePicBig(sourceString){
    document.getElementById("bigPic").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("bigPic").src = sourceString;
    $("#bigPic").animate({width:320, height: 586}, 3000);
}
```

css

```
#bigPic{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this function:

```
function onLoadFunction(){
    document.getElementById("bigPic").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Change `makePicBig()` to this:

```
function makePicBig(sourceString){
    document.getElementById("bigPic").src = sourceString;
    document.getElementById("bigPic").className = document.getElementById("bigPic").className + "visible";
}
```

And add some css:

```
#bigPic{
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    transition: width 3s, height 3s;
}
#bigPic.visible{
    visibility: visible;
    width: 320px;
    height: 586px;
}
```

Comment: Won´t work!
I guess the problem is with the "..className=..."
I didn´t give the bigPic a class. Just an ID.

Comment: Oh, `document.getElementById("bigPic").className = "visible"` then?